# How to set url in Django?

Tags: python, html, css, django, url

I'm a newbie in web development and I'm learning to use Django. Unfortunately I have been stuck for more than 24 hours trying to figure out how to set the URL of a web page. I keep getting status 404 error displayed on the browser after running python server. I have checked python documentation and other documentations online but I still don't see anywhere I'm getting it wrong.
I have the following files in the main Django follow:
urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlspatterns [
    path('qbank', include ('qbank.url')),
    path ('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

settings.py

```
INSTALLED APPS = [
'qbank'
.....
]
```

In my project folder(which I named **qbank**) I have the following files:
urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlspatterns = [
    path ('qbank'), views.index, name = 'index'
]
```

view.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse ('Hello from Qbank')
```

Comment: Exactly what URL did you try?

Comment: In your main urls.py, it should be 'qbank.urls' and not 'qbank.url' I think it's a spelling mistake.

Comment: On the browser I tried reaching for localhost:8000/qbank

Comment: I just tried qbank.urls but it didn't work too

Comment: @C-Bizz: the way you wrote it now, you access it with `localhost:8000/qbankqbank`.

Comment: @Willem Van I'm confused. Please which url am I supposed to access on the web browser to get the content of my app displayed on the browser? How do I correct the error to access it through `qbank/` on the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you wrote it now, it will require two `qbank`s, one for the "root" `urls.py`, and one for the `urls.py` in the `qbanks`, hence `localhost:8000/qbankqbank`. If you only want to access it with `qbank`, then you remove the `qbank` for example from the `urls.py` of the `qbanks` app. So then the "root" `urls.py` looks like:

```
# project_name/urls.py

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlspatterns [
    path('qbank/', include('qbank.url')),
    path ('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

and the `urls.py` of your app:

```
# qbank/urls.py

from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlspatterns = [
    path ('', views.index, name='index')
]
```